# Text in fading area turns black

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

My code for qml popup notification window (expects context parameters `owner` (object), `messageText`, `messageTitle` and `messageTimeout`) is the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Window {
    id: notification
    x: Screen.width - width - 40
    y: 40
    width: 350
    height: background.height
    color: "transparent"
    flags: Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint

    Component.onCompleted: visible = true

    signal closeRequested

    Connections {
        target: owner
        onInitClose: {
            if (closeInitialized) {
                return
            }

            fadeTimer.stop()
            fadeOutAnimation.start()
            closeTimer.start()
        }
    }

    property int fadeoutDuration: 1000
    property bool closeInitialized: false

    NumberAnimation {
        id: fadeOutAnimation
        target: background
        property: "opacity"
        duration: fadeoutDuration
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        from: 1
        to: 0
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        radius: 5
        color: "#D8226222"

        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: childrenRect.height + 20

        Label {
            id: caption
            color: "white"
            font.pixelSize: 18
            wrapMode: "WordWrap";

            text: messageTitle

            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 15
            anchors.rightMargin: 15
        }

        Label {
            color: "white"
            font.pixelSize: 14
            wrapMode: "WordWrap";

            text: messageText

            anchors.top: caption.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 15
            anchors.rightMargin: 15
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: fadeTimer
        interval: messageTimeout
        running: true
        repeat: false

        onTriggered: {
            closeInitialized = true
            fadeOutAnimation.start()
            closeTimer.start()
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: closeTimer
        interval: fadeoutDuration
        running: false
        repeat: false

        onTriggered: {
            notification.close()
            owner.onClosed()
        }
    }
}
```

So the idea is, we show the window consisting of semi-transparent area with two labels, the timer is started which when triggered begins fadeout (opacity from 1 to 0) animation and starts another timer (this time to close the window then the fading is complete).

The problem is - while background area is fading, text color changes from white to (seemingly non-transparent) black although the text is in container which is supposed to become absolutely transparent.  How can I fix this?

The owner cpp class code

```
#include "popup.h"

#include <QQmlContext>

Popup::Popup(QString title, QString text, int delay, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), m_engine(this)
{
    m_engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("messageTitle", QVariant(title));
    m_engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("messageText", QVariant(text));
    m_engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("messageTimeout", QVariant(delay));
    m_engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("owner", this);
    m_engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/popup.qml")));

    m_state = STATE_ACTIVE;
}

bool Popup::isOpen()
{
    return m_state == STATE_ACTIVE;
}

void Popup::onClosed()
{
    m_state = STATE_CLOSED;
    emit closed();
}

void Popup::close()
{
    if (!isOpen()) {
        return;
    }

    emit initClose();
}
```

Comment: What OS / WM do you use?

Comment: @folibis I reproduced it in Ubuntu 15.04, windows 10 (kvm) and two installations of windows 8.1 (not wm)

Comment: Could you provide a zip of the bug, I'd love to help you :)

Comment: I suspect that this is  graphics driver issue, as it works fine running through software raster on an openSUSE VM.

Comment: I agree with @cmannett85 : I've tested the code and on my Win7 machine the `Rectangle` as well as the `Text` turns black and then disappears, i.e. `opacity` does not work at all. Couldn't test on my Mac book, though.

Comment: So I guess we need a workaround for windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be fixed by adding 'layer.enabled: true' into background

```
Rectangle {
    id: background
    layer.enabled: true
    ...
}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be some totally random thing not mentioned anywhere... Anyway, thanks and congratulations with a rep boost! :)